# ECMAScript 6 what is scope?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't understand it:

https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject:

> With parameter *scope*.
>
> See also: [14.4.12](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject).
>
> *FunctionDeclaration* : `function` *BindingIdentifier* `(` *FormalParameters* `)` `{` *FunctionBody* `}`
>
> 1. If the function code for *FunctionDeclaration* is [strict mode code](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), let *strict* be **true**. Otherwise let *strict* be **false**.
> 2. Let *name* be StringValue of *BindingIdentifier.*
> 3. Let *F* be [FunctionCreate](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-functioncreate)(Normal, *FormalParameters*, *FunctionBody, scope*, *strict*).
> 4. Perform [MakeConstructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-makeconstructor)(*F*).
> 5. Perform [SetFunctionName](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname)(*F*, *name*).
> 6. Return *F*.

What is equal to the *scope* (Look at parameters of **FunctionCreate**)? In ECMAScript no one word about *scope*. And what does ‘with parameter scope’ mean?

Comment: Uh, I can find the term "scope" 189 times in that linked document.

Comment: @Bergi I mean in the specification there is no definition of the term "scope"

Comment: There are no definitions for most of the used variable names, but this one was sensibly chosen because it just means [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the `InstantiateFunctionObject` algorithm has a parameter that is subsequently referred to by the name "scope". A value is passed to this when the procedure is applied, e.g. in

> Let `fo` be the result of performing `InstantiateFunctionObject` for `f` *with argument* `lexEnv`.

In general, the scope refers to the lexical environment in which the function is defined and that it will close over.